# How to print sum of 2 numbers in scala?

Tags: scala

I am completely new to Scala. I like to add 2 numbers in scala. However I am not getting any output. Can anyone please help?
I am getting the output as "Sum is ()"

The below code should give the output as "Sum is 15".

```
object test1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit={
    val obj= new A();
    println("Sum is " + obj.curr())
    
  }
}
class A{
  private var value=6
  
  def curr()={
    var result= value +9
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, the return value of a method is the last expression.

In your case `curr()` returns `Unit` (no value).

To make it return a value, change it to:

```scala
  def curr(): Int = {
    var result= value +9
    result
  }
```

Note that you can actually just write it as the following:

```scala
def curr(): Int = value + 9
```

Also note that I've added the return type of the method explicitly, this is a good practice as it will raise a compilation error if you don't return the type that you said you would return.

---

More generally, if you're new to Scala, take the time to learn the basics and the idiomatic way to write Scala.

For instance, `var`s are to be avoided unless strictly necessary and locally scoped.

Comment: Thanks sir for explaining. It worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

the method `curr` is returning a `Unit` value. If you are using an IDE, you can make the program infer the type for you. In scala, the last line is what is going to be returned. You define the method like

```scala
def curr()={
  var result= value +9
}
```

the last line in this case is the `var` you defined with the name `result`. This expression returns a value of type `Unit`. You could refactor that function as the following

```scala
def curr: Int = value + 9
```

As you can see, you don't need to assing the result of the sum to a variable and then return it. Just putting the expression you need as the last line will be enough.